# Can the property of non-Newtonian fluid be controlled?

Tags: non-newtonian-fluids

I understand that non-newtonian fluid could become solid under high shear rate. What I can't find online, is could we control at which shear rate the NNF would solidify? Like when an electrical field with field strength A is applied to the NNF, the NNF would only start solidifying under shear rate X, but when the field strength is B the NNF would only start solidifying under shear rate Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one such  example is called *electro-rheological* fluid, in which the viscosity can be locally controlled by application of an electric field. This can be used in mechanical systems to clutch drive shafts in and out of engagement electrically, with no moving parts to wear out. Certain Honda cars use this to switch in and out of four-wheel drive in response to signals from slippage sensors in the wheels of the car.

Comment: But this electrorheological fliud is not non-newtonian.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [paper by MIT students](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6800318/) that may be helpful. Also a [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYTerCbDUzE) for reference.